# Invoice API: How to get payment fee?

Tags: api, paypal, invoice

I am currently using the PayPal Invoice API to create, send, and get status of PayPal invoices.

I am getting Sent/Paid/Error status using the GetInvoiceDetails API.

See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/invoicing/GetInvoiceDetails_API_Operation/

I am attempting to get the PayPal fee charged from a Paid invoice, but I cannot find it anywhere in the documentation.

How can I get the PayPal fee from a paid invoice using the Invoice API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your query, Once you get the PaypalPaymentid in GetInvoiceDetails API call then you can make a further API call ( GetTransactionDetails) with that transaction id . This will give you the fee details charged for that invoice. I have tried at my end and it worked for me and should work for you as well.